# Comments not getting deleted

Tags: discussion, bug, questions, comments

I am unable to delete one of the comments that I made. A dialog appears as expected asking me to confirm if I want to delete the comment, but no matter how many times it is clicked, the dialog never disappears and even after a wait of 5 mins nothing happens. A reload shows that the comments were all still there and the delete did not work. I now have two comments, which look almost the same. Not much damage done. But is this a bug?

link
[Mongodb update array with another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157626/mongodb-update-array-with-another-field)

Comment: Where are these comments? A link would be helpful. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear I have added a link. Thanks

Comment: I was able to remove that comment without any issues... Does anything turn up in your browser's dev tools? Any javascript errors?

Comment: @AnnaLear thanks for removing the comment. There were no javascript errors that I could find. Nothing turned up at all. Neither the Ok button nor the Cancel button was working.

Comment: Can you delete other comments?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No actually I haven't been able to delete any comments. Is it maybe something to do with my new user-ness??

Comment: OK, please use Chrome browser for the purpose of debugging. Press F12 and go to the "Network" tab. Try to delete the comment and confirm the dialog. Hopefully you will see new request in the open network tab, like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/flBHd.png). Now click on the name and you will get "Response" tab to the right. Click it and copy the contents here. For me it returns `{"Success":true,"Warning":false,"NewScore":-1,"Refresh":false}`.

Comment: thanks. I think it is the fact that I am using an old version of Firefox that is causing the problem.

Comment: @Sai still having the same problem?

Comment: @m0sa Yeah I now think it is an OS issue. I use Open SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop.